# Usar Python con Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, vscode, jupyter

Tengo descargado python (tanto en anaconda como fuera de anaconda) y tengo instaladas varias extensiones de python en Visual Studio Code y la de Jupyter Notbook. Aún así, cada vez que intento ejecutar una celda de Jupyter me salta el mensaje siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Puede ser que tengas que cambiar el interprete de python en el Visual Studio Code

Comment: Y eso cómo lo hago?

Comment: De forma predeterminada, la extensión de Python busca y usa el primer intérprete de Python que encuentra en la ruta del sistema.  Para seleccionar un entorno específico, use el comando Python: Seleccionar intérprete de la paleta de comandos (Ctrl + Shift + P). Dime si eso responde tu pregunta, Saludos....